# Sum Filtered Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have these rows:

```
value1 | value2 | value3
-------------------------
1231234|23423423|B
2342345|12309123|X
3242344|53453453|X
3453454|45345344|I
2531534|53434534|X
6657555|42342234|I
3242343|34534345|B
```

I want to filter and sum filtered value2 without filtering value1.

What is better way to do such case?

Current column sum Query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(value1),
    SUM(CASE WHEN (value3 = 'B' OR value3 = 'I') THEN value2 ELSE 0 END) FROM t
```

With this method the cost is 6 hours for 300k rows.

Expected Pre-Result:

```
value1 | value2 | value3
-------------------------
1231234|23423423|B
2342345|0       |X
3242344|0       |X
3453454|45345344|I
2531534|0       |X
6657555|42342234|I
3242343|34534345|B
```

Answer (score 4):

This will be faster in the `where` clause:

```
select sum(value2)
from t
where value3 in ('B', 'I')
```

This will be faster with an index on `(value3, value2)`.

However, this query should not take 6 hours for 300k rows.  That would only happen if the table is really a view, a very, very, very complicated view.

Comment: There's no filtering of Value 1 in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, but a query that simple should not take 6 hours for 300,000 rows.  I suspect there's something else going on that is hurting performance.

You could *try* doing is as a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(value1),
    (SELECT SUM(value2) FROM t WHERE value3 IN ('B','I'))
    FROM t
```

But it shouldn't make a dramatic difference unless there are VERY few B and I records and you have an index on `value3`.

Or, if you have access to a good DBA or SQL developer have them look at the query plan to see if something else is causing the performance issues.